# Why does \@afterheading after one tcolorbox disable the before option for later tcolorboxes?

Tags: tcolorbox

In the following mwe, the code in the `before={...}` has no effect. I believe this is related to the sentence "Also, it is not used, if the box follows a heading immediately..." from the `tcolorbox` documentation on the `before` option (p. 81 for `tcolorbox` version 4.5.1), but here the boxes do not *immediately* follow a heading. Is this a bug in the package or am I misunderstanding something?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{tcolorbox}[after={\@afterheading}]\end{tcolorbox}

abcd

\begin{tcolorbox}[before={test}]\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[before={test}]\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It shows if I add `ignore nobreak=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after` code is in a group and so your `\@afterheading` is partly ineffective. The `\@nobreaktrue`  is executed globally by LaTeX, but the `\everypar` setting which should reset the boolean at the next paragraph is then lost. Use `\aftergroup`, or use the `env/tcolorbox/after` hook instead of the `after` key with `\AddToHookNext{env/tcolorbox/after}{\@afterheading}`. This requires a current LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\begin{tcolorbox}[after={\aftergroup\@afterheading}]\end{tcolorbox}

abcd 

\begin{tcolorbox}[before={test}]\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[before={test}]\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]